# Походження слова "альфонс"

Tags: етимологія

[Стаття](http://bukinfo.com.ua/show/news?lid=103852) *"У Чернівцях на 10 років засудили **альфонса**-грабіжника, який підсипав жінкам снодійне в алкоголь"*

СУМ-20

> ***[АЛЬФОНС](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=958&page=40)*** а, ч., зневажл. Коханець, що перебуває на утриманні жінки. *– Держить вона альфонса, .. платить йому добрі гроші* (А.
> Кримський).

Яке походження має слово ***"альфонс"***?

Comment: Чесно кажучи, не зрозумів цього запитання. Походження слова надає СУМ. Детальна story-behind — це поза топіком Ukrainian_Language.SE

Comment: @bytebuster, де СУМ надає походження? Він надає лише значення. Ви мали на увалі ЕСУМ?

Comment: @bytebuster походження наче справді немає.

Comment: @Sasha думаю, bytebuster таки мав на увазі ЕСУМ.

Comment: @bytebuster я запитую походження, а не визначення (значення) слово. В етимолоґічному словнику не знайшла.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Альфонс (Alfons, Alfonse, Alfonso, Alphonsus, Αλφόνσος) — чоловіче ім'я.

[Російська Вікіпедія](//ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81) і [Російський Вікісловник](//ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81) стверджують, що використання цього імені в ролі загальної назви чоловіка, що перебуває на утриманні жінки, почалося після п'єси [Александра Дюма (сина)](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80_%D0%94%D1%8E%D0%BC%D0%B0_(%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD)) під назвою «Пан Альфонс» («Monsieur Alphonse», 1873), де був персонаж із відповідним іменем.

Саме ім'я Альфонс, за твердженням [Англійської Вікіпедії](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphons) і [Англійського Вікісловника](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Alfonso), походить від поєднання готських *** (**aþals*,  «благородний»; споріднене зі старонімецьким *adal* із тим же значенням) і *** (**funs*, «готовий»; Російська вікіпедія (див. посилання вище) вточнює це значення як «готовий [до бою]»).